# API for Post Stats for Self-Hosted Wordpress using JetPack

Tags: api, plugin-jetpack, wordpress.com-hosting

**EDITED** for Clarification

WordPress.com as well as JetPack provides stats (like no of views, referrer, etc) for various posts and blog as described here :[Wordpress Stats](http://en.support.wordpress.com/stats/)

Is there an API so that I can access the stats data and use it as per my needs ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is asking for a recommendation. To me it sounds more like if the OP wants to know if there is _any_ API that makes any sort of stats available publically. Like XML-RPC but in the reversed order or RSS with more specific infos than just the latest posts/comments, etc.

Comment: @brasofilo: I'm not asking for recommendation. I'm asking about sole existence of any API about post statistics as i am unable to find any such. Infact you can assume it as a type of analytics API. Please note, that i'm aware of GA. I want to know if any API can provide post analytic data via XML-RPC or JetPack ?

Comment: I misread the context, close vote retracted. Would be nice if you [edit] the Question to include this clarification and maybe a bit of @kaiser's feedback.

Comment: @VikasRaturi XML-RPC is in long: _Xross MarkUp Language - Remote *Publishing* Protocol_, so this won't help you. As in my comment above stated, it's about sending data _towards_ WordPress, not retrieving it from there. Maybe you should update your question as ***Brasofilo*** mentioned, show us _what exactly_ you're trying to retrieve, etc.

Comment: brasofilo, kaiser : edited question for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a Stats API that will allow you to access stats from a WordPress.com or a Jetpack site.

You can read more about it here:

- http://stats.wordpress.com/csv.php
- http://phoxis.org/2011/04/24/wordpress-com-stats-api/
- http://wpgr.org/2013/03/02/rendering-jetpack-stats/

Jetpack uses this API to populate the Top Posts widget:

- http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/jetpack/tags/2.5/modules/widgets/top-posts.php#L223